# Reverse 4 finger swipe direction on Windows 10, HP

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion, synaptics-touchpad

I recently installed Windows 10 Education, Version 1709, Build 16299.192.
Coming from a Linux background, I like everything about the Desktop. 
So my HP has four-finger touchpad support. A tap brings up the Action Center. A four-finger swipe kinda works but with issues. 
A swipe to the right, for people used to Natural Scrolling, is supposed to push the current desktop away to the swipe direction. And I guess that's how it works on certain devices. But on my HP it just goes to the next desktop in the swipe direction.

Also, note that my Natural Scrolling works just fine.
Thank you!

Comment: Does your trackpad use Synaptics drivers?  If so, I am looking for the same solution.